# Database driven application means?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I heard spring Framework should also be used to develop database driven applications.
what is exactly database driven application means?

Comment: Edited the question, asked for single clarifications .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every application that persists data about you in a database to tailor the user experience to you is a database-driven app.

Examples :

Facebook saves your data so it knows who your friends are, the posts you have made and liked.

Twitter saves all of your tweets in a database, much like Facebook.

Uber uses databases to keep track of who needs to be picked up, who just got picked up, who needs to be charged how much, and how much to pay each driver, etc.

You can see full explanation here [database-driven-application](https://www.quora.com/What-is-a-database-driven-application)

So we can achieve this using spring like [best-approach-to-creating-a-database-driven-java-website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2603229/best-approach-to-creating-a-database-driven-java-website)